# Cannot exit emacs within terminal in ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, emacs

I'm running emacs in my terminal on ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ emacs -nw
```

If I try to exit with `C-x C-c`, I see this in the chord space at the bottom:

```
C-x-
```

I'm an Emacs newb but this looks like its trying to make a joined chord with the `c` key even though I lift my finger way up over the `Ctrl` key. If I just hit `c` I get

```
C-x c is undefined
```

Now if I run emacs normally in the pop up editor, I'm able to exit just fine. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It sounds rather like Emacs isn't receiving `C-c`. Perhaps your window manager (or something else) is capturing that key before it reaches Emacs.

Answer (score 2):

I have been trying multiple combinations and suddenly Ctrl+Z worked (guess i am the lucky one xD ) 
So I tried it again and it is working. 
PS : my keyboard is AZERTY

Comment: Ctrl+Z will _suspend_ emacs, see [Exiting Emacs](https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/emacs/html_node/emacs_18.html).

Answer (score 1):

C-x C-c means Control-X, then Control-C. You're keeping the control key down, while you press x, then c

Comment: Thats what i thought at first too, but i made sure to release the control key after hitting x

Comment: No- I mean C-x C-c means "keep the control key down". If you let up on the control key, that's C-x c, which afaik doesn't mean anything.

Comment: I'm doing that too. In detail these are the actions I'm taking: I hold ctrl down and press x. Then I release ctrl and x. Then I hold ctrl down and press c. In the pop up editor it works fine so i dont think theres anything wrong with my "key-pressing technique" haha. It seems to be something with the in-terminal emacs editor.

Answer (score 1):

You might have overloaded the C-c command.

The default shortcut in ubuntu for the copy command is C-Shift-c, but some users change it to C-c in their settings. 
If you've done that, emacs won't close at C-x C-c cause it's recognizing the C-c as the copy command.

Answer (score 0):

Every Emacs keystroke corresponds to an interactive command with a name; as long as `M-x` is not disabled, you can use it to type the command

```
M-x save-buffers-kill-emacs
```

You can find which command a keystroke corresponds to with `C-h` `k` `<keystroke>` (the command is called `describe-key`).

If you have misplaced the meta key, too, `Esc` `x` is usually also bound to `execute-extended-command` which is the command which prompts for the name of a command to execute.

You'll probably eventually also want to learn `M-:` which allows you to enter arbitrary Lisp expressions for evaluation; the one to exit Emacs is then

```
(save-buffers-kill-emacs)
```

or if you want to bind a new keystroke for C-x, try

```
(global-set-key "\C-l" (lookup-key global-map "\C-x"))
```

to assign <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> as an alias for `C-x`.