# How to exit emacs text editor in Ubuntu terminal?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, emacs

So I'm in a file and can't get out, I'm on SSH so can't reset terminal. Can anyone help? There is no information online that I can find, 99% of the results are about Vim but I'm not using Vim.

I've tried `CTRL+C`, `CTRL+D`, `:quit`, `exit`, `quit`, `ESC` and many more,

I've also tried all options in the opposite case.

Comment: Googling "emacs exit" says Ctrl-x Ctrl-c `ZZ` or `:q!` does it for me. Oh. Hang on. That is for a real editor ;-)

Comment: I've tried both once and together, neither has helped me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot exit emacs within terminal in ubuntu 14.04](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813934/cannot-exit-emacs-within-terminal-in-ubuntu-14-04)

Answer (score 3):

There's multiple ways which worked for me, here they are.

Option one was to press `CTRL+X+C`, the `X` first is important.

Although you said you had tried this, so on to option two. Do what I said above, but putting `C` first, then you should have an input at the bottom, enter `!` and it should exit the editor.

You're welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Hold the Ctrl button. Press 'x' button, release it, then press 'c' button: [Exit Emacs](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20903/how-can-i-quit-emacs-from-within-a-term-within-emacs)

Answer (score 0):

Reading the answers and the comments, it is very strange, that Ctrl+x then Ctrl+c is not working. All key combinations in Emacs are bound to commands, also Ctrl+x Ctrl-c. It is bound to the command

`save-buffers-kill-terminal`

So what you can try is press Alt-x to execute a command. You should see M-x in the minibueffer at the bottom of emacs. then enter save-buffers-kill-terminal and voilá, you exited emacs. (Emacs will ask, if you have unsaved buffers or running processes, otherwise it will exit directly)
Hope this helps.