# How do I exit Emacs from the terminal?

Tags: emacs, key-bindings

I just installed Emacs 26.3 on Ubuntu 20.04.  I opened a buffer in the terminal, and I cannot close it.  `C-x C-c` does nothing.  `f10` to activate the menu does not activate the menu.

I'm using a `.emacs` file that maps cut/copy/paste commands to the normal `C-x/C-c/C-v`.  I don't think that this can affect the issue, however, because I have the exact same setup (including the same `.emacs` file) on by Emacs 24.5/Ubuntu 16.04 laptop, and it has no problem exiting with `C-x C-c`.  Also, I had the exact same problem before I installed the `.emacs` file on the new system.

How do I kill Emacs?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26813934/cannot-exit-emacs-within-terminal-in-ubuntu-14-04) exists, but it has no useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

`ESC x save-buffers-kill-terminal`

OFC binding `C-x` will affect `C-x C-c`. You don't need to know anything about Emacs to realize the problem. Just think twice.

Comment: I did think twice.  My first thought was, "Maybe binding 'cut' to `C-x` in my `.emacs` file is causing a problem."  Then, my second thought was, "I have empirical proof that binding 'cut' to `C-x` in my `.emacs` file does not have to prevent `C-x C-c` from being recognized as the kill shortcut, because I do it every day on my laptop that uses the exact same `.emacs` file."

Comment: Emacs in a terminal is a much more constrained beast, with fewer keystrokes available to it and the terminal and OS interfering more.

Comment: @BoreaDeitz how do you bind C-x to cut?

Comment: @nichijou I think it would be plausible to have `C-x` be `cut` if and only if the mark is active, and otherwise have its usual meaning. And indeed after a little research, it turns out this is exactly what [cua-mode](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode) does. That said, I don't see why it wouldn't work in a terminal. Emacs is perfectly capable of doing whatever it wants with C-c and C-x in a terminal; only stuff like C-z is unpreventable, and many non-letter control characters can't be encoded.